# Formatting Date/Time in Ruby to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to format the Time.Now function to show YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS instead of: "2018-03-09 09:47:19 +0000" The function needs to be placed within the Time.Now function.

```
 require ‘roo’
 require ‘roo-xls’
 require ‘byebug’
 file_name = ARGV.first || “Template.xlsx”
 excel_file = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(“./#{file_name}“, extension: :xlsx)
 xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: ‘ISO-8859-15’) do |xml|
 xml.LIEFERUNG
```

(“xmlns”: “http://testtest“, “xmlns:xsi”: “testtesttest”, “xsi:schemaLocation”: “testestest”, “version”: “1.0", “erstellzeit”: “#{Time.now.strftime(“%F %H:%M:%S”)}“, “stufe”: “Produktion”) do

```
 xml.ABSENDER do
 xml.KREDITGEBERNR “1206992”
 xml.Name “ALL”
 end
 xml.MELDUNGGROMIO(“erstellzeit”: “#{Time.now.strftime(“%F %H:%M:%S”)}“) do
 xml.MELDER do
 xml.KREDITGEBERNR “55093629”
 xml.Name “Finance”
 end
 File.open(“output.xml”, “w”) { |file| file.write(xml) }
```

Comment: It looks like you try to create some JSON manually? Can you please add some context. Why do you want to include a time format into your JSON that is not precise and can be misunderstood?

Comment: I am generating an xml file, I want to put a time string in the xml and for this reason is why I need to do this.

Comment: the xml is generated off an excel file referring to different columns

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `Time#strftime` method to format the time into a variety of different formats, including the one which you need. It takes a parameter which specifies the format of the date output. Look at the [documentation for this method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for more instructions about how to use it.

```
Time.now.strftime("%F %T")
```

The `%F` specifies that we would like the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. This is followed by a space, then the `%T` specifier, which produces a `HH:MM:SS` time output.

To incorporate this into your code:

```
"erstellzeit": "#{Time.now.strftime("%F %T")}"
```

Alternatively, if you're getting an additional `+0000` output, try:

```
"erstellzeit": "#{Time.now.strftime("%F %H:%M:%S")}"
```

Comment: It produces this at the end of the time: +0000"

Comment: @GLH That's odd, I don't get that on my machine (Windows 10, Ruby 2.4). I've modified my answer so that it should work for you.

Comment: I am using a MacBook and unfortunately I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: @GLH Is there any chance you could post the complete code?

Comment: Added the code to the original question now

Comment: In your code, you don't appear to ever actually save the changed XML, but I'm not famiiar with the `roo` gem.

Comment: I use this at the end: File.open(“output.xml”, “w”) { |file| file.write(xml) }

Comment: Hi, my fault this does work what you had suggested I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) module will do the work.

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Details
%Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
%m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)
%d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)

%H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, zero-padded (00..23)
%M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
%S - Second of the minute (00..59)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime`

`"erstellzeit": Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: It produces:
<MELDUNGGROMIO erstellzeit=“2018-03-09 09:47:19 +0000”>

Comment: Can you please review code addition above to see why the extra +0000 exists